# Resize Image when Display in View MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
<img src="http://imageshack.com/a/img89/5184/boo4.jpg">
```

I need to display an image on View but this image is to big ,How can i resize it to 30x30 when display on the View ?

```
<img src="~/Content/image.jpg?w=30&h=30&mode=strengh" />
```

If i use image from folder ,i can resize it by using ImageResizer .

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="~/Content/image.jpg" style="height : 30px;width : 30px;" />
```